# Varying number of NSArrays to fill

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, dictionary, nsarray

I'm working on an app that i need a little help with,

Basically i'm creating and populating some arrays and dictionaries from a database, However up until now the number of arrays and dictionaries has not changed, I now need to be able to have varying numbers (No more than 8 - Which is what i've been using till now)

I'm just not sure how to only work through a certain number of the requests, Can anyone help?

The code below is what i'm running currently so it works, but i need to be able to only populate/create between 1 & 8 instead of just my standard 8.

```
NSMutableArray *selections = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in arSelectedRows) {
    [selections addObject:[tableDataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}

NSArray *Category1 = [DBAdapter GetQuestionsfromid:[[selections objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"_id"]];
NSArray *Category2 = [DBAdapter GetQuestionsfromid:[[selections objectAtIndex:1] valueForKey:@"_id"]];
NSArray *Category3 = [DBAdapter GetQuestionsfromid:[[selections objectAtIndex:2] valueForKey:@"_id"]];
NSArray *Category4 = [DBAdapter GetQuestionsfromid:[[selections objectAtIndex:3] valueForKey:@"_id"]];
NSArray *Category5 = [DBAdapter GetQuestionsfromid:[[selections objectAtIndex:4] valueForKey:@"_id"]];
NSArray *Category6 = [DBAdapter GetQuestionsfromid:[[selections objectAtIndex:5] valueForKey:@"_id"]];
NSArray *Category7 = [DBAdapter GetQuestionsfromid:[[selections objectAtIndex:6] valueForKey:@"_id"]];
NSArray *Category8 = [DBAdapter GetQuestionsfromid:[[selections objectAtIndex:7] valueForKey:@"_id"]];

NSDictionary *cat1 = [DBAdapter GetCategoryDictionary:[[selections objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"_id"]];
NSDictionary *cat2 = [DBAdapter GetCategoryDictionary:[[selections objectAtIndex:1] valueForKey:@"_id"]];
NSDictionary *cat3 = [DBAdapter GetCategoryDictionary:[[selections objectAtIndex:2] valueForKey:@"_id"]];
NSDictionary *cat4 = [DBAdapter GetCategoryDictionary:[[selections objectAtIndex:3] valueForKey:@"_id"]];
NSDictionary *cat5 = [DBAdapter GetCategoryDictionary:[[selections objectAtIndex:4] valueForKey:@"_id"]];
NSDictionary *cat6 = [DBAdapter GetCategoryDictionary:[[selections objectAtIndex:5] valueForKey:@"_id"]];
NSDictionary *cat7 = [DBAdapter GetCategoryDictionary:[[selections objectAtIndex:6] valueForKey:@"_id"]];
NSDictionary *cat8 = [DBAdapter GetCategoryDictionary:[[selections objectAtIndex:7] valueForKey:@"_id"]];
```

DBAdaptor is my Database class file. selections contains the number of arrays/dictionaries that need to be created.

Any help would be amazing!

Thank you.

Comment: This is where one would use (surprise!) an array.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have the varying number in;

```
int count;
```

You can iterate through a loop like; (Also, you would probably want to save these arrays and dictionaries)

```
NSMutableArray* arrayHolder = [NSMutableArray new];
NSMutableArray* categoryHolder = [NSMutableArray new];

for(int i = 0 ; i < count ; i++)
{
    NSArray* newArray = [DBAdapter GetQuestionsfromid:[[selections objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"_id"]];
    NSDictionary* newCategory = [DBAdapter GetCategoryDictionary:[[selections objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"_id"]];

    [arrayHolder addObject:newArray];
    [categoryHolder addObject:newCategory];
}
```